# TYPO3 sitepackage: How to access PSR-7 Request Object or TYPO3_REQUEST in TCA/Overrides?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-11.x, psr-7

I’m in TYPO3 11.5. In my sitepackage extension I need to access the **TYPO3 request object** in either `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` or a custom class method. But I don’t know how to instantiate the PSR-7 request object nor is the old style `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']` available in either of the two files (I get the warning that it’s undefined).

### Questions:

- How can I instantiate the PSR-7 request object in either the TCA override or my custom class?
- If that’s not possible, why can’t I get access to `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']`?

### Background:

In `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` of my sitepackage extension I define several **custom content elements.** To make it a little easier I write their configuration (CType, showItem, flexform, …) into an array and then iterate through it, calling a custom class method. This class method calls the `ExtensionManagementUtility` methods `addTcaSelectItem` and `addPiFlexFormValue` for each content element.

That all works. But now I want to add a condition based on the site object (my sitepackage should run on two different sites) and I try to get the site information using the **TYPO3 request object.** The [documentation on the TYPO3 request object](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Typo3Request.html#user-function) tells me that I need to pass it as an argument to a user function – but it does not tell me how to instantiate it.

### Code snippets:

My code snippets show different unsuccessful attempts (v1, v2) of accessing the request object in tt_content.php and in my class method.

#### Snippet of `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```php
// ... defining associative array $ce with CType names as key ...
// then calling my class method on each $ce element:

$addCEObj = new \Vendor\Sitepackage\Utility\AddContentElement;
$addAfter = 'textmedia';
foreach ($ce as $CType => $tcaConf) {
    // $tcaConf contains 'showItem', 'colOverrides', 'flexform' and the localised title
    $tcaConf['CType'] = $CType;
    $tcaConf['addAfter'] = $addAfter;
    /* (v1a) */ $addCEObj->tca($tcaConf, $request);
    /* (v1b) */ $addCEObj->tca($tcaConf, $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']);
    /* (v2)  */ $addCEObj->tca($tcaConf);
    $addAfter = $CType;
}
```

#### Snippet of `Classes/Utility/AddContentElement`:

```php
class AddContentElement
{
    /**
     * used for v2
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'];
    }

    /* (v1) */ public static function tca(array $tcaConf, ServerRequestInterface $request)
    /* (v2) */ public function tca(array $tcaConf)
    {
        /* (v1) */ $site = $request->getAttribute('site');
        /* (v2) */ $site = $this->$request->getAttribute('site');
        $siteId = $site->getIdentifier();
        
        // ... adding the content element to the TCA based on site identifier using:
        ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(...);
        ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCA is generated once then and cached. accessing the request. is a bad idea in this context. there might not even a request if the first instance which needs TCA is CLI command.

so therefore i would strongly suggest not to use this king of thing. but rather
use TSconfig to disable the content elements you don' want on a certain site.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#removeitems

Comment: Thank you! This works … even though it feels weird, to first add CEs and then remove them again.

Comment: TS config is more on the line of setting policies for users or pages. so you system is capable of having all these content elements but a users is not allowed to use all of the capabilities (in all places)